# SQL - Counting sets of Field-B values for each Field-A value

Tags: sql, logic, set

First of all sorry that I could not think of a more descriptive title.

What I want to do is the following using only SQL:

I have some lists of strings, list1, list2 and list3.

I have a dataset that contains two interesting columns, A and B. Column A contains a TransactionID and column B contains an ItemID.

Naturally, there can be multiple rows that share the same TransactionIDs.

I need to catch those transactions that have at least one ItemID in each and every list (list1 *AND* list2 *AND* list3).

I also need to count how many times does that happen for each transaction.
[EDIT] That is, count how many full sets of ItemIDs there are for each TransactionID", "Full Set" being any element of the list1 with any element of the list2 with any element of the list3

I hope that makes enough sense, perhaps I will be able to explain it better with a clear head.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you also have some sort of primary key or unique constraint on any column or columns in your table? Or can there be completely identical duplicated rows?

Comment: What database? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: Are list1, list2, and list3 tables, with one string per row? If not, what do you mean by "lists of strings"?

Also, I don't understand "I also need to count how many times does that happen for each transaction".  Count how many times what happens for each transaction?

Comment: The answer that I found the most helpful was Mark's. Thank you everyone for helping and sorry that I did not express myself very clear!

Comment: And to answer the above questions:

I'm using MSSQL, even though, as I dared to assume, the solution didn't involve any dialect-specific logic.

@Marcus:
list1,list2,list3 are just logical groups of strings that could be defined/stored in any way necessary.

And what I meant with "count how many times does that happen for each transaction" was "count how many full sets of ItemIDs there are for each TransactionID", "Full Set" being any element of the list1 with any element of the list2 with any element of the list3.

That is, in Mark Byer's answer:
min(list1_count,list2_count,list3_count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL if you have the following lists:

```
list1 = ('1', '3')
list2 = ('2', '3')
list3 = ('3', '5')
```

then you can do this:

```
SELECT
    TransactionID,
    SUM(ItemID IN ('1', '3')) AS list1_count,
    SUM(ItemID IN ('2', '3')) AS list2_count,
    SUM(ItemID IN ('3', '5')) AS list3_count
FROM table1
GROUP BY TransactionID
HAVING list1_count > 0 AND list2_count > 0 AND list3_count > 0
```

Result:

```
TransactionId  list1_count  list2_count  list3_count
1              3            2            1
3              2            2            1
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID INT NOT NULL, TransactionID INT NOT NULL, ItemID INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, TransactionID, ItemID) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 1, 4),
(5, 1, 1),
(6, 2, 1),
(7, 2, 2),
(8, 2, 1),
(9, 2, 4),
(10, 3, 3),
(11, 3, 2),
(12, 3, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your dialect, and assuming your lists are other tables...

```
SELECT
    TransactionID, Count1, Count2, Count3
FROM
    MyDataSet M
    JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*), ItemID AS Count1 FROM List1 GROUP BY ItemID) T1 ON T1.ItemID = M.ItemID
    JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*), ItemID AS Count2 FROM List2 GROUP BY ItemID) T2 ON T2.ItemID = M.ItemID
    JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*), ItemID AS Count3 FROM List3 GROUP BY ItemID) T3 ON T3.ItemID = M.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

If list1, list2, and list3 are actually known enumerations, you could go with:

```
SELECT TransactionID, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE ItemID IN (list1) AND ItemID IN (list2) AND ItemID IN (list3)
GROUP BY TransactionID
```

If you have a lot of lists, you may want to generate the SQL in a program.  However, it should still perform pretty well, even for a lot of lists.  Put the lists you expect to have the fewest matches in first, so that you stop evaluating the predicate as soon as possible.

If your lists are in another table, perhaps a bunch of tuples of the form (list_id, item_id), that's a trickier problem.  I'd like to know more before trying to come up with a query for that.